# Unable to use dict sent from Django to template

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have the following dict in python which I send to the template:

```
mydict = {
    "ABC": {
        "target_weight": 1,
        "target_ra_weight": 2
    },
    "XYZ": {
        "target_weight": 3,
        "target_ra_weight": 4
    },
    "JKL": {
        "target_weight": 5,
        "target_ra_weight": 6
    }
}
return render(request, 'template.html', {'mydict': mydict})
```

I can't seem to assign this to a javascript variable and access the content. I have tried all of the following in the javascript section of my template:

```
var mydict = {{ mydict }};
> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token {

var mydict = {{ mydict|safe }};
> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token {

var mydict = {{ mydict|escapejs }};
> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token {
```

The following allows me to create the variable, but when I try to access it (eg: console.log(mydict)), then I an error:

```
var mydict = JSON.parse('{{ mydict }}');
console.log(mydict);
> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token { in JSON at position 1
// same thing happens when using |safe or |escapejs
```

Comment: What about serialize it to JSON before passing it to the template Or using `__str__()` method to use the `JSON.parse` afterward in javascript?

Comment: How does the generated html look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need JSON, not dict. Use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) function:

```
import json

mydict = {
    "ABC": {
        "target_weight": 1,
        "target_ra_weight": 2
    },
    "XYZ": {
        "target_weight": 3,
        "target_ra_weight": 4
    },
    "JKL": {
        "target_weight": 5,
        "target_ra_weight": 6
    }
}
return render(request, 'template.html', {'mydict': json.dumps(mydict)})
```

and in template:

```
var mydict = JSON.parse('{{ mydict|safe }}');
```

Comment: No luck. I get the exact same errors. I tried all the same variations as per my original question, but first using json.dumps as you suggested. Same errors.

Comment: @darkpool You'll need to parse it to JSON in your templates using `JSON.parse('{{ mydict|safe }}')`.